# Attribute to refrsh the Div Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, sharepoint-jsom

I have a `div` tag with html table which is getting data
   dynamically.

I would like to refresh the div tag every 5 seconds.

Can any one help me in knowing if there is attribute for div tag to refresh it?

Comment: `setTimeout` or `setInterval` javascript functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Answer (score -2):

The proper way to achieve this is to use HTML5 expando attribute "data-" and then in your JavaScript function you can get the value from expando attribute and refresh the div content. In that way you can make refresh interval configurable.